# Catalog View and CatalogSearch Layer equivalent class in Magento2

Tags: magento2

How to override this method in Magento2 from the below class?

```
\Block\Catalog\Layer\View.php

\Block\CatalogSearch\Layer.php

canShowBlock(){...}
```

Does both the classes above override \app\code\Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation.php class in Magento2 , cause both classes have canShowBlock() in Magento 1
??

Comment: Above path is correct for magento-2 ?

Comment: is it correct or u confirming with '?'

Comment: Add full path with path.

Comment: Updated full path